# How much is maximum value of og:ttl of facebook sharing?

Tags: facebook, sharing

Context: Share a webpage on facebook wall of users

- Share a webpage with a image
- After some minutes, the image is deleted from my website
- About some days (7 or use og:ttl), the webpage is re-scraped. In the sharing post on facebook wall, the image is lost.
- Hope that the image of the sharing post will never be lost. Thus, og:ttl should be set very-large value.

At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties?locale=en, og:ttl has minimum value 345600 seconds (4 days). But maximum value is not given.

1. How much is maximum allowed value of og:ttl of facebook sharing? Could I set very-large value (3153600000 ~ 100 years ~ forever) for the tag?
2. In case that the very-large value is allowed, Whether is the webpage still re-scraped but the time is not expired?

Comment: No you can not set forever. You can not use Facebook to store your images.

Comment: But Facebook note that they will re-scrap the image after some days. Mean that they will cache image in that days. So could they cache the image in longer time (such as some years) by og:ttl?

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: Thanks. And final question that what maximum value is accepted of og:ttl tag?

Comment: Does it matter? ttl is just the recommended time to cache it. There is nothing that say that Facebook will not scrape you earlier.

Comment: This is a very legitimate question and I hope someone has an answer for it. The Facebook bot is unnecessarily slamming the bandwidth of our website re-scraping everything every 7 days.

Answer (score 5):

According to Facebook, the maximum `og:ttl` value is `2419200` seconds. That's equivalent to 28 days.

I came to this answer by setting my `og:ttl` to a very large number, then used the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) to scrape the page. The debugger returned an error: `The og:ttl property must be an integer between 345600 and 2419200.`